# What would happen to the earth if we removed nearly all of the air?

Tags: earth-system, air

I wanted to know : what if someone pulled a really strong vacuum and prevented any air to enter. Would the earth be destroyed or nothing much would happen? I am not talking about the people and other living organisms, but what would happen to the planet itself.

Thanks in advance.
(Sorry if off-topic)

Comment: The Earth's atmosphere is already pulled on by a really strong vacuum, a vacuum whose quality is orders of magnitude higher than any vacuum that can be created in a laboratory. Yet the Earth only loses a tiny, tiny bit of its atmosphere per year to space.

Comment: @DavidHammen I agree with your point.  But what if we pulled a vacuum stronger than that of space, and sucked air even from the core. I get it that the vacuum in space is stronger than anything achievable by scientists, but what if we could pull a vacuum stronger than that, hypothetically speaking.

Comment: @Aster17 World building questions are handled on World Building SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about a current situaion or even remotely plausible. It belongs on World building.

Comment: Or perhaps it belongs to Space Exploration because of the relevance of this situation to Mars.

Comment: @gansub Thanks for letting me know which Stack Exchange it belongs to. I will delete this question shortly.

Answer (score 3):

We already have a model of an atmosphere-stripped Earth at hand, it's called **Mars**. Essentially, the loss of air on Mars meant more things didn't happen any longer than did happen. Erosion and corrosion processes caused by the air -- and by fine particles carried by the air-- largely stopped with the loss of a thick atmosphere, effectively freezing mineral deposits. As a result, explorations of the Martian surface may be used to identify areas that were exposed versus those that were protected (as if by a body of water).

For example, we may look at [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40874/28871) at Space Exploration Stack Exchange, which summarizes the minerals found at various depths in the Gale Crater on Mars. Note especially the relative concentrations of mafic rock and iron oxides; the former is converted to the latter upon exposure to an oxidizing atmosphere. We see that the upper reaches, which likely would have been exposed when Mars had a thick atmosphere, still have the iron oxides produced by oxidation of the mafic rock, whereas the mafic matter below which might have been protected by a lake has remained largely intact.

Comment: I agree that Mars is stripped of air, but I am asking what if all of the air, even the one in the crust, were to be sucked out.